# How many functors are there from $\mathbf{Set}$ to $\mathbf{2}$?

Tags: category-theory

I saw this question in the lecture notes "Programming with Categories" by Brandon Fong.
The question is very simple:

> How many functors are there from $\mathbf{Set}$ to $\mathbf{2}$? Write
> them down.

To clarify, $\mathbf{2}$ is the category composed of two object, i.e. $\{1,2\}$ and one morphism $f$ from $1$ to $2$.

At first sight, this seems like an infinite number of possible functor.
But, when I try to construct the possible functors, I can come up with three possibilities.

I mean, one possibility is sending everything to object $1$, and the other would be to send everything to $2$. Another possibility would be to send $\varnothing$ to $1$ and everything else to $2$, and then sending every void function, i.e. $\varnothing \mapsto X : X \in Ob_{\mathbf{Set}}$, to $f$.

What else am I missing? Is the actual answer infinity?

Comment: That's all. Those are all the cases, which get forced due to $\hom(\emptyset,A)$ and $hom(A,B)$, in Set, being non-empty for $A,B\neq \emptyset$, while $hom(2,1)=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right.

If for sets $a$ and $b$ there are arrows in both directions - $a \to b$ and $b \to a$ - then they both have to be sent to the same object, for there are no arrows in both directions between $1$ and $2$ in $\mathbf{2}$. This means that all nonempty sets have to be sent to the same object. As for the empty set, it can always be safely sent to $1$, and can only be sent to $2$ if everything else is sent to $2$.